# TFS upgrade still pointing at old tfs source

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've upgraded my TFS server on to a new machine using the upgrade wizard.

I've also added this to my server list in visual studio.

However it’s connecting to the old tfs server not the new one.

I've checked in changes whilst running profiler and I can see the code running against the old server.

Is there a place where I'm supposed to change the settings so that changes are going to the new server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the full instructions for moving TFS to new hardware:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx

Comment: is this applicable when your upgrading from an older version of TFS?

Comment: Its applicable any time that you are moving hardware. If you are upgrading in place you don't need this.